Error: unable to find network path in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

I am having problems with the connection in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. When I enter server name, login account name and pass, I keep getting the error in the attached image. the data I entered is correct, because a colleague of mine can log in correctly. How can I solve this?
thanks!
Tried restarting the service, uninstalling it, and tried entering a new rule in firewall, but it does not solve.

@AlwaysLearning the mention of "Named Pipes" in the error message is a red herring.  The TCP/IP connection failed, and Named Pipes was used as a fallback, which also failed.  This is normal TCP/IP connection troubleshooting.

To solve the The server was not found or was not accessible message in SQL Server:

Make sure that the SQL Server instance you are trying to connect to is configured in SQL Server Configuration Manager to allow remote connections. By default, SQL Server might only accept connections from the local machine.

The SQL Server Browser service is responsible for locating SQL Server instances on a network. Make sure that the SQL Server Browser service is running on the SQL Server machine. You can configure the SQL Server Browser service using the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

If you have a firewall enabled on the SQL Server machine, ensure that it has an exception for the port used by SQL Server (usually port 1433). You might need to add a rule to allow inbound traffic on that port for your specific network connection.

Verify that your computer can ping the SQL Server machine at its specific IP .


